# Does all of three: Presto, hive and impala support Avro data format?

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, presto

I am clear about the Serde available in Hive to support Avro schema for data formats. Comfortable in using avro with hive.

[AvroSerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe)

for say, I have found this issue against presto.
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/5009

I need to choose components for fast execution cycle. Presto and impala provide much smaller execution cycle.
So, Anyone please let me clarify that which would be better in different data formats.
Primarily, I am looking for avro support with Presto now.

However, lets consider following data formats stored on HDFS:

1. Avro format
2. Parquet format
3. Orc format

Which is the best to use with high performance on different data formats.
?? please suggest.

Comment: Impala is a querying engine that is mostly used to query over tables that are already present in Hive.

Comment: my question is about what are the better ways to choose query engine and tech stack. I know impala is query engine provided from cloudera only.  However, I am looking for comparative study here.

Comment: for say, hiveQL is taking 23secs for select count(*) from table, however, presto SQL is taking 2 secs for same cluster size. So, what does impala's performance and how does the different data formats performance for same dataset,

Comment: http://www.svds.com/dataformats/

Comment: Thanks!! this gave little answer but still I am looking for presto insights.

Comment: anyone from presto community can provide details of Avro support in Presto.???

Comment: got another bug on presto github related to avro on presto:
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/8154

Answer (score 1):

- **Impala** can read Avro data but can not write it. Please refer to [this documentaion page](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/impala_file_formats.html) describing the file formats supported by Impala.
- **Hive** [supports](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/FileFormats) both reading and writing Avro files.
- **Presto**'s Hive Connector supports Avro as well. Thanks to David Phillips for pointing out [this documentaion page](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#supported-file-types).

There are different benchmarks on the internet about performance, but I would not like to link to a specific one as results heavily depend on the exact use case benchmarked.

Comment: Presto supports Avro now: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#supported-file-types

Comment: Thanks zoltan and david, however I have attempted with avro support but schema for avro data not readable with Presto.

Comment: we have opened one ticket on presto git hub. https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/8154 
However, responses are very slow from presto team. provided the schema also

Comment: we have tried out one solution from AvroSerde and it worked for Presto queries. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe . Point here is : specify avro schema as TBLPROPERTIES( avro.schema.literal="{..}" ) For example : TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.literal'='{
      "namespace": "com.howdy",
      "name": "some_schema",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [ { "name":"string1","type":"string"}]
    }');

Comment: issue exist with 'avro.schema.url' TBLPROPERTIES. this property not understood by Presto and throw schema not found exception.